# Cache a result for a certain amount of time and return a cached value

Tags: haskell

I want to do the following thing: a method `getSessionToken` which would:

- make a request to a server if a "`cachedSessionToken`" is outdated (made more than 1 hour ago)
- once it has made the request to the server, it saves a result to a "`variable`" and then returns it whenever `getSessionToken` is called

So the idea is cache a result and return is when needed, otherwise make the request to the server `getSessionTokenRemote` first, cache it and only after that return the result. I'm not interested in exact implementation of `getSessionTokenRemote`, however, it could be something like this:

```
getSessionTokenRemote :: IO String
-- or just
getSessionTokenRemote :: String
```

whatever is the best fit.

I wonder, how do I do that in a pure functional language such Haskell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want `getSessionTokenRemote` to write to a variable, you have to pass it one, e.g. give it a type like:

```
type CacheInfo = {- you've got to fill this bit in -}
getSessionTokenRemote :: IORef CacheInfo -> IO String
```

The implementation is not too hard once you take a type like this.

An alternative, if you're into implementation-hiding, is to write a value which produces `getSessionTokenRemote` values. Assuming an internal implementation of the type above and some empty cache value `emptyCacheInfo`, that could be done like this:

```
getGetSessionTokenRemote :: IO (IO String)
getGetSessionTokenRemote = getSessionTokenRemote <$> newIORef emptyCacheInfo
```

This is an `IO` action which, when executed, produces a session-token-acquiring action with a fresh cache.

Comment: could you please explain how `type CacheInfo`, `newIORef` and `emptyCacheInfo` could be implemented?

Comment: @Alex `newIORef` is provided by [`Data.IORef`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-IORef.html#v:newIORef). As for implementing `CacheInfo` and friends, well... what have you tried? What went wrong?

Comment: I just can't figure out how to "write" into CacheInfo because Haskell doesn't have variables. How and where do I store a value in Haskell?

Answer (score 3):

Haskell does have stateful variables, but they are 'managed'.  They inevitably run in some monad, and you have to explicitly read from / write to them.  `IORef`, `MVar`, `TVar` and friends are all 'managed refs' (I first heard that term used in the Clojure community).

Here's a gruesomely simplified example of how you might use a ref type to set something up.

```
import Data.IORef
import Network.HTTP

data SessionToken = SessionToken {
    _timeHours :: Int
  , _token     :: String
  }

getSessionToken :: IORef SessionToken -> IO String
getSessionToken cacheRef = do
  cachedToken <- readIORef cacheRef
  if   _timeHours cachedToken > 1
  then do 
    newToken <- getSessionTokenRemote
    writeIORef cacheRef newToken
    return $ _token newToken
  else return $ _token cachedToken

getSessionTokenRemote :: IO SessionToken
getSessionTokenRemote = do
  tokenRequest <- simpleHTTP $ getRequest "http://jtobin.ca/sample_token.txt"
  token        <- getResponseBody tokenRequest
  return $ SessionToken 0 token

main :: IO ()
main = do
  tokenRef <- newIORef $ SessionToken 0 "my token"
  getSessionToken tokenRef >>= putStrLn

  writeIORef tokenRef $ SessionToken 2 "my token"
  getSessionToken tokenRef >>= putStrLn
```

Comment: tokenRef <- newIORef $ SessionToken 0 "my token" -- does this mean I have to know a token? But at first I don't know it.